# RuntimeException treated as ServerSOAPFaultException

Tags: java, exception, vavr

Why following code:

```
/.../
.onFailure(exc ->
                        Match(exc).of(
                                Case($(instanceOf(ServerSOAPFaultException.class)), handleServerSOAPFaultException(exc)),
                                Case($(instanceOf(Exception.class)), handleDefaultException(exc))
                        ))
                .getOrElseGet(exc -> false);
```

invoke first case when exception is RuntimeException. RuntimeException is not an instance of ServerSOAPFaultException.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Java problem, not a Vavr specific one: in Java, if you write `foo(a, b)` then both `a` and `b` will be evaluated before `foo(a, b)` is evaluated (called "eager").

So to evaluate the `Match().of()` it must evaluate all `Case()`. To evaluate each `Case()` it must evaluate `handleServerSOAPFaultException(exc)`.

If you want to evaluate `handleServerSOAPFaultException(exc)` only when the case matches, you need to make it a lazy call, i.e. a function, i.e. a `Supplier`:

```
/.../
.onFailure(exc ->
                        Match(exc).of(
                                Case($(instanceOf(ServerSOAPFaultException.class)), () -> handleServerSOAPFaultException(exc)),
                                Case($(instanceOf(Exception.class)), () -> handleDefaultException(exc))
                        ))
                .getOrElseGet(exc -> false);
```